# How to create PNG to SVG so that each section can be addressed separately

Tags: html, svg

I have a image which has property layout in it, I want each section(plot) of this layout as a independent entity so that I can change color of each section and can provide identity to each section. Image is [image]

**Or is there any alternate of this like `html` etc.. ?**

Comment: Do you just have a PNG image of thethis?  It looks like it was originally some sort of vector file created with Illustrator, or something like that. Do you have the original vector file?

Comment: I have only PDF for this.

Comment: Check whether the PDF contains a bitmap for the map, or whether it uses vectors.  If it is the latter, then you should be able to convert it to an SVG with Illustrator, Inkscape etc.  If you can get it into SVG format (with vectors, not a bitmap), your task becomes a **lot** easier.

Comment: How can I check  that what kind of PDF it is ?

Comment: You can link to it here if you like. Or you could load it into Inkscape yourself and see whether the map is a solid uneditable bitmap, or if it is a whole lot of vector shapes (rectangles, text, trees, etc).

Comment: Inkscape is available for free on Windows Marketplace if you do not have it